# What is the Python equivalent of (Mel) Substitute, Maya

Tags: python, maya, substitution, mel

```
for j in Xjoints:
    j = substitute( XrigNamespace, j, '')
```

I'm looking to write a Python equivalent for Substitute, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `str.replace()` or is the `XrigNamespace` a regular expression?

Comment: If you don't use regular Expression, than its str.replace()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regular expression substitution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
test = "Hello -%there%-"
regularExpr = "-%.*%-"
s1 = re.sub(regularExpr, "Mel", test)
# Result: Hello Mel
s2 = re.sub("foo", "Mel", test)
# Result: Hello -%there%-
```

While it's obviously possible to write an equivalent in Python, the high level libraries already provided are there to be used (and will in this case certainly perform better).